# Trigger and handle Event async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, blazor, .net-5

I'm currently working on a .net 5 Blazor application.

I use events to pass data from one component to another.

Unfortunately my current logic is synchronous - but I would rather use an asynchronous event handler.

Thus, I need to use the following code to handle my event:

```
Task.Run(async () => await ChangeNumbers());
```

Is there a possibility to handle events asynchronously without Task.Run?

- My State service looks like this:

```
public class MyComponentState
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    
    // Is there a way to declare this event Action async??
    public event Action OnChange;

    public void DoStuff(int myNumber)
    {
        MyNumber = myNumber;

        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

- The component to handle the state looks like this:

```
public class MyOtherComponentDisplay : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    public MyComponentState MyComponentState { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // this should all be handled async... i could use OnInitializedAsync
        MyComponentState.OnChange += OnChangeHandler;
    }

    private void OnChangeHandler()
    {
        // Is there a way to handle/declare this without Task.Run(async ...) - but async right away??
        Task.Run(async () => await ChangeNumbers());
    }

    private async Task ChangeNumbers()
    {
        // Some operations with MyComponentState.MyNumber async needed!!!

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyComponentState.OnChange -= OnChangeHandler;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare and handle events async?

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Blazor Server or Wasm?

Comment: Wasm Hosted - it's in the Wasm part.

Comment: Then Task.Run() makes no sense - at best it's a no-op.

Comment: The problem is the following code: public event Action OnChange;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic adoptation would be an `async void` handler:

```
private async void OnChangeHandler()
{
    // Is there a way to handle/declare this without Task.Run(async ...) 
    // - but async right away??

    // Task.Run(async () => await ChangeNumbers());
    await ChangeNumbers();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);  // probably needed
}
```

Comment: Could using an "async void event-handler" cause other problems that one should be aware of?

Comment: And reason why now: `private async void OnChangeHandler()`?

Answer (score 4):

The way you're doing things looks strange to me.  That's not how I do events in Blazor.  (Maybe you're coming from Web Forms?)

Generally, a custom event is defined like:

***MyControl.razor***

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<SomeType> EventName{ get; set; }

@code {
    someMethod (){
        EventName.InvokeAsync(SomeType data);
    } 
}
```

And the handler in the consuming control can be async if you want:

***MyPage.razor***

```
<MyControl EventName=OnChangeHandler />

@code {
    private async Task OnChangeHandler()
    {
        await ChangeNumbers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your approach works fine from Child > Parent component. I handle the Child event in the parent component. In my case, I need to handle the parent event in the child component - I use a state handler therefor.

Comment: Please refer to this link under 3. State container: https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you want to subscribe to the parent's events, you can pass a reference to the parent as a value using `<CascadingParameter Value=this >` and in the child `[Parameter] ParentControl PC {get; set;}` then subscribe to the event as `PC.Event += . . . `

Comment: Yes, I can pass the parent to the child and call a method on the ref :) ...For me it works better to simply use an event... Thank you!!